# Express a "not equal to A or B" criterion in Select

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list of pairs of strings: `myPairsList`. I wish to [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) all the pairs that do not contain `"A"` or `"B"`. Unlike functions such as [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) that use patterns as input, the function [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) uses a *criterion* (*"crit"*) as input.

A verbose way to execute my desired selection is:

```
Select[myPairsList, (#[[1]] != "A") &&
  (#[[1]] != "B") && (#[[2]] != "A") && (#[[2]] != "B") &]
```

> {{"X", "Y"}, {"Y", "X"}}

Perhaps a more elegant way to execute the selection is:

```
Select[myPairsList, (! MemberQ[{"A", "B"}, #[[1]]]) && 
  (! MemberQ[{"A", "B"}, #[[2]]]) &]
```

> {{"X", "Y"}, {"Y", "X"}}

But, what if I want to express the selection as "the first element is neither `"A"` nor `"B"`, and the second element is neither `"A"` nor `"B"`"?

To do that, I tried the following:

```
Select[myPairsList, (#[[1]] != ("A" || "B")) && (#[[2]] != ("A" || "B")) &]
Select[myPairsList, (#[[1]] != ("A" | "B")) && (#[[2]] != ("A" | "B")) &]
```

> {}

> {}

But, as you can see, I don't obtain my desired output, so I'm clearly using the incorrect syntax. So what is the correct way to express "not equal to A or B"?

Comment: `Select[myPairsList, FreeQ[#, "A" | "B"] &]`

Comment: Are your strings always single character strings?

Comment: @lericr That's a good point. No, my strings are not always single character strings.

Answer (score 8):

Example input:

```
SeedRandom[1];
myPairsList = RandomChoice[{"A", "B", "X", "Y"}, {40, 2}]

{{"Y", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {"B", "A"}, {"A", "A"}, {"B", "Y"}, {"A", 
  "A"}, {"A", "A"}, {"X", "A"}, {"B", "X"}, {"A", "A"}, {"Y", 
  "Y"}, {"Y", "B"}, {"B", "A"}, {"A", "B"}, {"Y", "A"}, {"X", 
  "A"}, {"B", "B"}, {"Y", "Y"}, {"Y", "X"}, {"Y", "X"}, {"A", 
  "B"}, {"Y", "Y"}, {"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}, {"A", "Y"}, {"A", 
  "X"}, {"Y", "A"}, {"X", "X"}, {"A", "B"}, {"Y", "X"}, {"B", 
  "X"}, {"A", "A"}, {"A", "X"}, {"B", "X"}, {"B", "A"}, {"X", 
  "Y"}, {"B", "B"}, {"B", "A"}, {"Y", "X"}, {"A", "Y"}}
```

---

Some of the ways could be:

```
Select[ContainsNone[{"A", "B"}]][myPairsList]
```

As Bob Hanlon suggested:

```
Select[FreeQ["A" | "B"]][myPairsList]
```

or its counterpart:

```
Select[Not@*MemberQ["A" | "B"]][myPairsList]
```

---

```
DeleteCases[myPairsList, {x___, OrderlessPatternSequence["A" | "B"], 
  y___}]

Select[Nor[MemberQ[#, "A"], MemberQ[#, "B"]] &][myPairsList]
```

---

Result:

> {{"Y", "Y"}, {"Y", "Y"}, {"Y", "X"}, {"Y", "X"}, {"Y", "Y"}, {"X",
> "X"}, {"Y", "X"}, {"X", "Y"}, {"Y", "X"}}

Comment: This is great. But I forgot to mention in my original post that I would prefer that the solution be compatible with *Mathematica* 9 and later. It looks like `ContainsNone` was introduced in 10.2.

Comment: I realized that as soon as I had typed it in. Please see update.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the strings are not always single characters, we may want to use some string specific functions, specifically `StringFreeQ`.

```
Select[myPairsList, Apply[And]@*StringFreeQ[{"A", "B"}]]
```

`StringFreeQ` can work on a list (your pairs are just lists), but it keeps the list structure, so we need to do a logical **and** on that list, thus the `Apply[And]`.